# Quickblox does not work on API 11 - javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: No peer certificate

Tags: android, certificate, message, quickblox

I am trying to use QuickBlox for Android. My App connects and works well using push notifications on different android models using API 17. On devices with API 11, I get the following error :

W/System.err﹕ javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: No peer certificate
W/System.err﹕ at org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.SSLSessionImpl.getPeerCertificates(SSLSessionImpl.java:265)
W/System.err﹕ at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.AbstractVerifier.verify(AbstractVerifier.java:93)
W/System.err﹕ at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.createSocket(SSLSocketFactory.java:388)
W/System.err﹕ at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:164)
W/System.err﹕ at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:164)
W/System.err﹕ at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:119)
W/System.err﹕ at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:359)
W/System.err﹕ at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:555)
W/System.err﹕ at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:487)
W/System.err﹕ at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:465)
W/System.err﹕ at com.quickblox.internal.core.server.HttpExecutor.execute(HttpExecutor.java:21)
W/System.err﹕ at com.quickblox.internal.core.server.HttpRequestRunnable.run(HttpRequestRunnable.java:50)
W/System.err﹕ at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:444)
W/System.err﹕ at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:306)
W/System.err﹕ at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
W/System.err﹕ at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1088)
W/System.err﹕ at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:581)
W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019)

This has been driving me nuts for days.. Can someone please help?

(I am using quickblox sdk V1.2.3 and V1.2.4. Both give the same results)

Comment: It was working, suddenly it stopped to work now, I can't figure out why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this call before create the QuickBlox Session

```
QBSettings.getInstance().setTransferProtocol(TransferProtocol.HTTP);
```

Also I prefer to migrate to QuickBlox Android SDK 2